# SharePoint 2013 date filter web part - what version needed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, filter

I have been searching, what version of SharePoint 2013 I need to use Date Filter Web Part.

Can I enable it on Foundation or do I need Standard for this? Or is it Enterprise feature only?

I can see those in SharePoint 2013 Enterprise:

[image: From menu]

[image: On page]

Comment: If you can get the webpart in webpart gallery than it will work for sure.

Comment: Well, the question is, do I need to enable it somewhere, because I don't see it in Foundation version and I can't find it in Standard as well..

Comment: Is below answer helps you to clear your idea about the webpart in SharePoint Foundation? Is that helps you?

Answer (score 1):

You are using SharePoint Foundation, that's why Date Filter web part is missing as **unfortunately it only comes with the Enterprise edition** of SharePoint.

If you still want to apply the **date filter** than there is a trick mentioned in below link which can help you to get desired output.

[Filter a SharePoint Calendar List With a Date Picker](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/filter-a-sharepoint-calendar-list-with-a-date-picker/)

Comment: Hmm, I try to check it out, but I have currently those Server Controls grayed out..

Comment: I already mentioned that, these webpart only comes with Enterprise edition not with Foundation. So ultimately the answer for your question is NO. I gave the alternate way to achieve it via link mentioned in my answer. That's it. Let me know if you need further help. :)

Comment: Did you found my answer helpful to understand the scenario?

Comment: I understand, that those filters come only with Enterprise, I'm talking about `Server Controls` in Designer, where I can't add `DateTimeControl`, because it's grayed out some why..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I settled with Excel filtering tools, since it's much easier to achieve and has everything I need built in already.